# Update elsticsearch index upsert document not working

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest

I am trying to update the elastic search index document created using dynamic object and UpdateRequest method in NEST API. But document is not getting upserted. I am using dynamic class as fields are dynamic for the object. deserializedDocumentDictinary is creted from Json object.
Following is the code we have used for updating document.

```
UpdateRequest<dynamic, dynamic> updateRequest = new UpdateRequest<dynamic, dynamic>((dynamic)deserializedDocumentDictinary, "indexname", "type", "id");
 updateRequest.DocAsUpsert = true;
 updateRequest.Doc = (dynamic)deserializedDocumentDictinary;
 IUpdateResponse<dynamic> updateResponse = EsClient.Update<dynamic, dynamic>(updateRequest);
```

Comment: `But document is not getting upserted` - what do you see? What do you expect to see? What does the JSON request look like? How are you checking if the update has been appllied / not been applied?

Comment: Hi Russ, I am getting following error:Request failed to execute. Call: Status code 407 from: POST /index/type/id/_update?retry_on_conflict=3
# Request:
<Request stream not captured or already read to completion by serializer. Set DisableDirectStreaming() on ConnectionSettings to force it to be set on the response.>. I updateRequest.Doc I can see entity to upsert. Do I need to any other configuration?

Comment: HTTP status code is `407 Proxy Authentication Required`: it looks like you have a proxy in front of Elasticsearch that requires authentication. You can specify proxy details on `ConnectionSettings` with `Proxy`: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/current/configuration-options.html

Comment: The request is valid. Next thing to look at is seeing what is actually being sent for the document. Take a look at the Troubleshooting section in documentation: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/current/troubleshooting.html

Comment: Thanks for your reply it works.